# Using Stylesheet in Python Pycharm

Tags: python, css, qt5

I am trying this code and it works, but the code "setStyleSheet ..." doesn't. 
It opens the window, but there is no border and no backgroundcolor change ...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtCore, Qt


class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()


        self.window.setWindowTitle('Our first Button')
        self.window.setGeometry(400,100,400,500)
        self.window.setStyleSheet('border:3 px solid #4e4e4e; background-color:6e6e6e')
        self.window.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())


main = MainWindow()
```

Comment: @AI Plan If the answer solved your Question, consider setting the answer as accepted. So others who search for a similar problem, can find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You missed the # before setting the color of the background `background-color:#6e6e6e;`
Also there was a space between the 3 and the px in the definition of the border.
 If you change it to the call below it should work

```
self.window.setStyleSheet("""
                           QMainWindow{border:3px solid #4e4e4e; background-color:#6e6e6e;}
                          """)
```